# How to show blank with a text in Power BI with creating measure?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Can anybody please tell me to create a measure that replaces the blank value with text?

Here is my situation. I have the `Vendor` field from the `Vendor table` and `CSM_Item_No` from the `Item table`. Most of the `CSM_Item_No` does not have a `Vendor` Name. I want to replace them with "No Vendor". I know there are so many ways you can do it, by using IF, ISBlank, etc., but when I create a measure I can't give Vendor Feild from the vendor table. This where I got stuck. Any help will be really appreciated.

[image]

See below it will not recognize my feilds. Is there any way I can get this done?
[image]
Thank you so much

Comment: Seems you don't have the proper relationship set between the tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below measure. Remember, this is not a replacement to the original column or value. But you can use this measure in table or other visual to show "No Vendor" where there is no data in the original column. This way you can keep original and customize both data.

```
vendor_name = 

var current_row_name = MIN(table_name[Name])

RETURN 
IF(
    current_row_name = BLANK(), 
    "No Vendor", 
    current_row_name
)
```

If you need a calculated column, you can try this below code-

```
vendor_name_column = 

var current_row_name = table_name[Name]

RETURN 
IF(
    current_row_name = BLANK(), 
    "No Vendor", 
    current_row_name
)
```

Comment: dude you arwesome. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can not resolve your probleme with a measure, its not what measures do. to resolve your probleme consider two approches :

1- the best solution is to replace blank values in [power query editor.](https://intellipaat.com/community/42268/how-to-replace-null-values-with-custom-values-in-power-bi-power-query-editor)

2- the second solution is using a calculated column with an if condition.